# Only pull Top X using Fluent NHibernate HasMany

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following mapping in Fluent-NHibernate Map

```
public class PostMap : ClassMap<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        Id(i => i.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.SiteId);
        Map(x => x.Message);
        Map(x => x.DateCreated);
        Map(x => x.DateModified);
        HasMany(x => x.Comments)
            .OrderBy("DateCreated DESC")
            .ReadOnly()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

There are a lot of comments on each post, what I would like to do is only bring back the top 5 from the db rather than remove them in code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should be possible with filters. Read here: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#filters

Comment: How are Filters helping here? I do need a TOP/TAKE and not a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually. Ignore the property `Comments` from `Post` mapping, and load it manually with `Take(X)`:

```
// query posts
foreach (var post in posts)
{
    post.Comments = Session.QueryOver<Comments>()
                        .Where(x => x.PostId == post.Id)
                        .Take(X)                       
                        .Future();
}
```

With `Future` instead of `List` it will do one DB roundtrip for all comments.